# Make a request to the Square Connect api to list the payments

Tags: c#, square-connect

I'm trying to make a request to the Square Connect api to list the payments. I'm receiving this error

"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

The api says
Open your favorite command-line application (such as Terminal if you're using a Mac) and run the following curl command, providing your access token where indicated: 
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers("Authorization") = "XXXXX";

HttpWebResponse response = null;
string responseMessage = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

Assert.IsNotNull(responseMessage);
```

Comment: In the above example, does the redacted value for your "Authorization" header include the word "Bearer" before the personal access token?

Comment: I'm going to be releasing a c# library to interact with their api in the near future. Are you interested?

Comment: @RonnieOverby Have gone down the path to making this C# library yet? I would be interested in it.

Comment: No. In fact, I can't remember having any intention of ever doing that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient();
        var request = new RestRequest("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments", Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx");
        //setHeaders(request);
        var Response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Make sure your accesstoken is not Expired. and also check authorize request than try later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

request.Headers("Authorization") = "XXXXX";

Do this

request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + yourPersonalAccessToken);